# Webfont (@font-face) line-height issue

Tags: font-face, webfonts, css

I often embed webfont (@font-face) in sites that I develop and I have never encountered a major problem until today.

In fact, I feel there is a big issue with the line-height, I'm not extremely good at English so I'll try to illustrate it with pictures. I already contact the support from fontshop.com (where the font was bought) but they do not seem to understand / solve the problem.

**What we had before with standard desktop font (= rendering is good for us):**

[image]

**What we had with the font-face (no change in CSS stylesheet):**

[image]

**Here is the CSS:**

```
#content h1 {
    background:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:"DINPro-Bold","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size:35px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: **Another picture to explain...** 

http://cl.ly/image/0h0K3I3O2t2V

Comment: Please post some code, preferable for a minimal case that demonstrates the issue. Also please explain why you think this is a line-height issue.

Comment: As a hint, see this image: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Typography_Line_Terms.svg&page=1 First: every font has some extra space at the top and the bottom, some more - some less, and every font is different. The only solution to this is - adjusting the element with margins / paddings until it fits. Using line-heights in the best way is to implement a "base-line-grid" like it is used in print-media - look at a newspaper: every text is "on line" :D

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Rockbot, I am aware that the problem can settle with padding / margin but I did not want to come to this technique a little "dirty" I think ... Is there a way to fix the height problem? I know that the font-face generator from Font Squirell website can adjust this issue, I did once with a different font but it would not let me upload this new font (FF DIN) ...

Anyway, I wonder if it does not come from the fact that I use a "text-transform: uppercase". Space at the bottom comes from the fact that it provides for the characters down to below the baseline ... Possible?

Comment: Try to remove the `text-transform` and see what happens :) I don´t know if there is a chance to edit the character-height of a font, sorry!

Comment: @Rockbot, look at the picture, it looks like it's not properly aligned to the baseline as it should be (as in the wikipedia's picture you sent) http://cl.ly/image/0R3O113o1N32

Comment: two more links on the issue: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/forum/discussion/8/line-height-issues-with-web-font/p1 and http://www.webfonts.info/webfonts-know-how/part-2-problem-line-height - here specially "point 3". Again - i think the issue is with the font!

Comment: If you find a solution - let us know please!

Comment: Yes @Rockbot I'll keep looking for now I solved the problem with padding, our client could not wait;)

Answer (score 5):

Usually font websites will have ways to configure the webfont package when you download it.  I buy all my fonts from myfonts.com and under the advanced settings there are options for line-height adjustments.  Try downloading the font using native line-height adjustments if this option is available.  If not, try uploading the font to fontsquirrel's online font generator and upload the new version.

Comment: Should be worth a note that altering the font files in any way is against almost every premium web font provider's terms of service.

Answer (score 5):

That's not the same font. The shape of the O and the curvature of the arm on the R give it away, which means the fallback fonts are being used, likely due to @font-face not loading properly. Different fonts will have different default spacing, as stated already, which would also lead you to believe it's a line-height issue.

Try making your fallback fonts something totally obvious, like:

```
font-family:"DINPro-Bold",serif;
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Generate the webfont at [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). After uploading the fonts select 'Expert', scroll down and check the checkbox 'X-height Matching'. This resizes the height to match the x-height.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with line-height of your webfont (especially if font suppose to be big in your project) try this: close your font in div or other block element and set "overflow" to "hidden". Div will have exact height of your font so any additional space will be cut off.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "position: relative; top: 5px;" to the "h1" tag

Answer (score -1):

Try position: relative; paddint-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px;

Answer (score -2):

Line height according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-height)

> In typography, leading (rhymes with heading) refers to the amount of
>   added vertical spacing between lines of type.

This can be achieved like this...

.class{
line-height: 1em; 
}

But if you are referring to the height of the letters then this is not something that can be adjusted. It is part of the font you have chosen to use.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding your question because I can't see a difference between the two images.

Comment: **Maybe it will be more clear with this picture?** http://cl.ly/image/1G2w2I3h281o

Comment: what about with !impotrant, you may have other conflicting styles. Feel free to post a fiddle and I will take a look.